# Leaflet - circleMarker not applying color tag

Tags: leaflet

I am creating a map for a game and I placed a bunch of circleMarkers, but they aren't changing colour based on the color or fillColor tags.

```
var Tenaland = L.circleMarker([-417, 385.0625], 45, {
color: '#f03',
fillColor: '#f03',
fillOpacity: 0.80
}).addTo(map);
```

They are defaulting to blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you use an incorrect signature for [`L.circleMarker`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circlemarker). The second argument is for the options, not for a radius.

```js
var Tenaland = L.circleMarker([-417, 385.0625], /*45,*/ {
    color: '#f03',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.80
}).addTo(map);
```

Then you can change its size using the [`.setRadius(pixels)`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circlemarker-setradius) method.

It is for [`L.circle`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle) that the 2nd argument defines the radius (in meters).

Comment: are you able to help me with this one? :D
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775318/leaflet-prevent-loading-tiles-outside-of-maxbounds